# Problems getting clean sunrise, sunset, civil, nautical and astronomical twilight data

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries, astronomy

If in a notebook you enter:

```
WolframAlphaResult["Sunrise june 25, 2013", {{"DaylightInformation", 1}, "ComputableData"},
                   PodStates -> {"DaylightInformation__More"}]
```

you get:

```
{{"begin astronomical twilight","3:16 am EDT"},
{"begin nautical twilight","4:07 am EDT"},
{"begin civil twilight", "4:50 am EDT"},
{"sunrise","5:24 am EDT"}, 
{"sunset", "8:31 pm EDT"}, 
{"end civil twilight","9:05 pm EDT"},
{"end nautical twilight","9:48 pm EDT"}, 
{"end astronomical twilight","10:39 pm EDT"},
{"duration of daylight", {15, 8}}}
```

as a result (I didn't know there was something called "nautical twilight," but now that I do, I want it).  Unfortunately, the result is returned not as a nice list, but instead embedded in a complicated `WolframAlphaResult` format. Despite trying many different approaches, I have been unable to discover a way to get just a list of this data returned. It is possible?

Comment: Have a look at `AstronomicalData[]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I did, but it seems to provide only sunrise and sunset (and, I think, moonrise and set).

Comment: @George Wolf nevermind, I guess there was a misunderstanding there. that's why I deleted my earlier comment ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WolframAlpha["Sunrise june 25, 2013", {{"DaylightInformation", 1}, 
   "ComputableData"}, PodStates -> {"DaylightInformation__More"}]
```

gives

> {{"begin astronomical twilight", 
>     "3:56 am PDT"}, {"begin nautical twilight", 
>     "4:40 am PDT"}, {"begin civil twilight", "5:18 am PDT"}, {"sunrise",
>      "5:49 am PDT"}, {"sunset", "8:33 pm PDT"}, {"end civil twilight", 
>     "9:04 pm PDT"}, {"end nautical twilight", 
>     "9:43 pm PDT"}, {"end astronomical twilight", 
>     "10:26 pm PDT"}, {"duration of daylight", {14, 44}}}

Comment: Really? Just drop the "Results" from WolframAlphaResults? That's embarrassingly simple. I tried a lot of different things but somehow not that.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, your question is the first time I came across the function `WolframAlphaResults`, and I cannot find any information in the docs (Mma version 8.0.4 Windows) about it. How did you find this function?

Comment: I expanded a wolfram alpha pod which displayed the extended twilight information. It contained the WolframAlphaResult[] function with the "DaylightInformation_More" PodState, and I copied it, not noticing the "Result" part added at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I was going to say the same thing. Here's a picture instead of me clicking in the little screw icon...

[image: wolfram alpha]

This pastes the query into your document (and runs it too):

```
WolframAlpha["Sunrise june 25, 2013", {{"DaylightInformation", 1}, 
  "ComputableData"}]
```

Then I assigned the results to a symbol for further processing.