# A femme is a wife is a Frau

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, wolfram-alpha-queries

As can be seen from

```
LanguageData["Properties"] // Multicolumn
```

[image]

Mathematica's translation capabilities seem to be very limited. It can translate month names, colors and numbers, but, apparently, not arbitrary words.

```
Grid[
 LanguageData[
  {
   Entity["Language", "English"],
   Entity["Language", "German"],
   Entity["Language", "Spanish"]
   }, "NumeralWords"],
 Frame -> All,
 Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

To translate arbitrary words one probably has to use `WolframAlpha`:

```
word = "femme";
trans = WolframAlpha[word <> " from french to german", "PodCells"]
```

[image]

This doesn' t look too bad, but how do we get "femme", "Frau" and "Ehefrau" as a `List` of `String`s ? Executing

```
trans // FullForm
```

we see a complex structure of `RowBoxes` - instructions. To eliminate the unwanted elements I have written

```
res =
 DeleteCases[
   Cases[trans, _String, Infinity],
   "\")\"" | "\"(\"" | "\" \"" | "\"  |  \"" | "Columns" | 
    "\"French\"" | "\"from\"" | "\"general\"" |
    "\"German\"" | "Output" | "\"person\"" | "Rows" | "RowDefault" | 
    "RowsIndexed" | "Times" |"\"to\"" | "\"translate\"" | "\[NoBreak]" | "Verdana",
   Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> {"\"femme\"", "\"Frau\"", "\"Ehefrau\"", "\"wife\"", "\"woman\""}

To eliminate the backslash characters:

```
str = ToCharacterCode[res] /. (34) -> Sequence[] // FromCharacterCode
```

> {"femme", "Frau", "Ehefrau", "wife", "woman"}

Since we want to translate from french to german we finally eliminate the englisch words :

```
Flatten @ Map[Intersection[DictionaryLookup[{#, All}], str] &,{"French", "German"}]
```

> {"femme", "Ehefrau", "Frau"}

Voilà, a femme is a wife is a Frau - but at what expense !

How can I simplify this code (especially the `RowBoxes` - destruction) ?

Are there alternate ways to translate simple words from one language to another ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following may be useful as starters:

```
WolframAlpha["femme from french to german",{{"Translation:TranslationData", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
(* {" Frau  |  Ehefrau", " Frau"} *)
```

Comment: Excellent! - how did you find this somehow arcane form?

Comment: I learned it from @George Wolfe in  [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14938/125)

Comment: @eldo: you probably have noticed it by now, but the point is that you don't have to "find" that form for a given WA call but just click on the small + icon in the "pod cell" of your choice and select the "computable data" entry. That will insert a new input cell with exatly that arcane code. That's explained also in one of the ansers (currently that is the last one) to the questions kguler refered to...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks, I didn't know this :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **kguler**'s marvelous solution I was able to write a little translation program. Due to a certain unreliability of `WolframAlpha` results it is far from being perfect, but fun to play with.

```
ToWords[res_] :=
 DeleteDuplicates @ StringTrim @ Flatten @ Map[StringSplit[#, "|"] &, res]

Translator[word_, from_, to_] :=
 ToWords @ WolframAlpha[word <> " from " <> from <> " to " <> to,
   {{"Translation:TranslationData", 1}, "ComputableData"}]

from = "german";
to = {"swedish", "french", "spanish", "portuguese", "italian"};

words = Translator["Nummer", from, #] & /@ to;
```

To equalize grid:

```
spaces = Map[Table[" ", {#}] &, Max[#] - #] &[Length /@ words];

Framed[
 Grid[
  Flatten /@ Transpose[{to, words, spaces}],
  Dividers -> All,
  Spacings -> {{2, 2}, 3},
  Alignment -> Left,
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
  Background -> {None, {{Hue[.6, .15, .9], GrayLevel[.9]}}},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, White]],
 FrameMargins -> 0.5,
 FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.7]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
TextTranslation["wife", #]& /@{"French","German","Spanish","Italian"}
```

> {Femme,Ehefrau,esposa,moglie}

Presumably, many other dictionaries are available as well.

---

On my Win7 machine, there is an authentication issue so it says:

> TextTranslation::notauth: TextTranslation requests are only valid when
> authenticated. Please try authenticating again.

On the cloud it tells you that you are accessing an external service and you have to agree to the terms.